# JPA NOT IN statement

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have a app that uses MySQL, JPA with EclipseLink.

I'm trying to get from the DB the collection of User flagged as "ACTIVE" and that are not already in a List already loaded in the application.

That is my method:

```
public List<User> findAllButUsers(List<User> users) {

    List<User> list = null;
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u NOT IN :users AND u.status = :status");
    query.setParameter("status", "ACTIVE");
    query.setParameter("users", users);

    list = query.getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

And the Log from server gives me that:

```
Fine:   SELECT iduser, create_time, email, name, password, salt, status FROM user WHERE ((iduser NOT IN (?)) AND (status = ?))
bind => [com.wa.gp.jpa.entities.User[ iduser=2 ], ACTIVE]
```

From the *bind => [**com.wa.gp.jpa.entities.User[ iduser=2 ]**, ACTIVE]* shows me that instead of binding the id it passes the value from User.toString method thus resulting in a Collection that includes the users passed. I thought it would work just sending the object to JPA and it would figure out the iduser by itself.

I don't know if it is a expected behavior, looks to me it is. How can I just make that query without having to change the valor from tostring in User? Do I have to instead of giving the List of Users just pass a List of the Ids? If that is the case I just became said.

Thanks